# Testing rotation on multiple devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, xcode-ui-testing

I am wanting to create a testing routine, which will create a screenshot from my most important screens. I will then view these screenshots separately to make sure I didn't mess things up.

My question is how do I properly initiate a rotation throughout a testing function. For some reason, when I tinker with the rotation I get all sorts of weird layout display errors.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
func testMainView() {

    XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .portrait

    XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Main Button is tapped portrait", block: { _ in

        XCUIApplication().buttons["Main"].tap()

        // takes a second for screen to load
        sleep(3)

        let screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
        let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
        attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
        add(attachment)

    })

    // going back to the menu
    XCUIApplication().buttons["Menu"].tap()

    // rotate device
    XCUIDevice.shared.orientation = .landscape

    // give time for rotation to finish
    sleep(3)

    XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Main Button is tapped landscape", block: { _ in

        XCUIApplication().buttons["Main"].tap()

        // takes a second for screen to load
        sleep(3)

        let screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
        let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
        attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
        add(attachment)

    })

}
```

I then call the test using `xcodebuild` and use multiple `destination`s and the option `resultBundlePath`

How else could one go about testing UI Layout on many devices in many orientations?Thanks

Joseph

Comment: Have you tried fastlane? https://fastlane.tools It allows you to automate taking screenshots for your app.

Comment: Not since they were bought. But will this solve the rotation issue mid-testing/screenshoting?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "I get all sorts of weird layout display errors.". I personally don't use fast lane. I kinda do it like you with a UITest target (see https://gist.github.com/TitouanVanBelle/69661dbcfb90d6fe8d00c4027ac7aac8)

Comment: @TitouandeBailleul i.e. I call the `.orientation` command and the device rotates. After calling it again the device does not rotate, just the content. It's really weird. Nothing that happens when using the app outside of this scenario. I'll give fastlane a look.

Comment: Ok. My suggestion would then to split the test into multiple tests. Start with 1 test per screenshot. You can then consider moving multiple screenshots into one test if it takes too long. What do you think?